# Scrolling through a viewport doesn't work with Hololens since using MRTK v2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm having trouble scrolling through a Viewport UI-Element I made.
Using the old HoloToolKit solutions won't do it for the new MRTK.

Since I've upgraded to MRTK v2 it doesn't work.
I am able to use the UI-Buttons from Unity.
But when I try to scroll it behaves elastic and always jumps back to the top.

Does anybody know what changes I have to make or which scripts to attach to make it work with MRTK v2?

I am using Unity 2019.2.12f and imported the MRTK v2.2.0

Comment: and is it to difficult to try the example package to look how to set it up?

Comment: Have you tried to use Scrolling object collection from MRTKv2? It supports scrolling pressable buttons and the ScrollingObjectCollection scene(in MixedRealityToolkit.Examples\Expermental\ScrollingObjectCollection) shows how to use it. (https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Experimental/ScrollingObjectCollection/README.html)

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT Thanks for the hint, yeah tried to use it with the NearinteractionTouchable script on the buttons and trying with the NearIntercationTouchablesUnityUI script. Both didn't work :S
Also changing the arrangement of within the hierarchy  didn't work.

Could it be that UI-elements are not yet supported?
Or would you recommend to redesign it without UI-Buttons?

Comment: Are you using the Button UI elements provided by Unity(UGUI)? Actually, MRTK provides a variety of button prefabs(https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Button.html), and it is recommended that you choose from them.

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm gonna give it a try.
Thought maybe there would be a "simpler" uGUI solution.